# Why WCF Service hosted inside windows service dies after some time

Tags: wcf

I have hosted a WCF service inside a Windows service using C#. It works fine and I was able to communicate with the WCF service from a client application.

But the issue is if I leave the client idle for 10 min or so and then try to connect again, I get the following error

> Server stack trace:
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)

Comment: You should show us the **exact and complete** exception message - not just a stack trace.....

Answer (score 0):

It is not the windows service that is down, it is your client proxy.

You say that you leave the client idle. You should not do this.  You should close the client after you have made your request. Then open it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

This happends when your service binding [ReceiveTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) setting is left at its default value (10 minutes).

To set this to "forever", you can set in your config file:

```
ReceiveTimeout = "infinite"
```

or by code:

```
binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
```